# Can't deploy websocket application in glassfish4 server

Tags: java, eclipse, websocket, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I am following the JavaEE7 Hands on lab by arun gupta.
https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-hol

I have deployed the application in JBoss Dev Studio +wildfly 8 server+Windows7. It's working fine.

But when i deploy the same in Windows8+Eclipse+Glassfish4 server, it throwing the following exception. Can some one let me know what is wrong with the setup in windows8?

cannot Deploy movieplex7
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while preparing the app : Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: Connection could not be allocated because: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused: connect.
Error Code: 0. Please see server.log for more details.

Answer (score 0):

"Error in allocating a connection" means you should check your datasource and see if it is working fine. Glassfish has a panel for datasources

Comment: Hi Can you let me how to check whether my data source is working or not in glassfish? Thanks in advance